# How do I insert a piece of information to an already existing record?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I have an SQL Database setup with rows of data already there. How do I update just one column of one row by grabbing the id (appointmentspage.php?id=1")?

I already have written the code to input the data into the correct position table I want, but I am having trouble selecting the id too

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
try{
$sql = "INSERT INTO appointments (Notes)
VALUES ('".$_POST["Notes"]."')";
```

I feel like `= $_GET['id'];` or  `WHERE appointments.ApptID = :id` should be used, but I can't fathom it.

Currently the 'Notes' column in my SQL table gets an input, but it creates a new empty row with only that data added. I want to select an existing row/entry and add the Notes to that.

Comment: Do you mean SQL's Update? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: [update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) is the sql command. Also note that while you’re learning sql and php, be sure to find up to date tutorials. I would recommend using pdo instead of mysqli, and be sure to use prepared statements. The code you have is insecure (the query should look like this: `update  appointments set Notes=? where I’d=? `  The `?` is a placeholder for user input. )

Comment: Thanks for this! I just do not know how to make this point to my user input area 'Notes' now.

Answer (score 2):

On my site I have a set of examples for the basic use cases, you are welcome to check them out.
Your case would be [UPDATE query using PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/update).

First of all, "insert into an existing record" is called **UPDATE**. You need to check out your SQL textbook.

And yes, you need something like ApptID = :id in your query. However personally I prefer simple ? marks

So it should be something like

```
$sql = "UPDATE appointments SET notes=? WHERE ApptID=?";
$stmt= $dpo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$notes, $id]);
```

Note three shouldn't be any `try` or catch stuff around.

Comment: Thank you for this, it's almost exactly what I need. I realise now that I did not add that I need the input to come from user filling out a textbox named Notes (let's call it txtNotes to save confusion). I tried things like this `$sql = "UPDATE appointments SET Notes=('".$_POST["Notes"]."') WHERE appointments.ApptID = :id";` but it did not work. Could you advise further?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define ApptID field as Primary Key with auto-increment field in database define.
 In MySQL, a primary key is a single field or combination of fields that uniquely defines a record. None of the fields that are part of the primary key can contain a NULL value. A table can have only one primary key.
Auto-increment allows a unique number to be generated automatically when a new record is inserted into a table. Often this is the primary key field that we would like to be created automatically every time a new record is inserted.
After that you can use that ApptID for update your existing data using Update query in MySQL